# Unable to install packages after deinstalling quagga 0.99.23

Tags: debian

I uninstalled today `quagga`  0.99.23 from a Debian Stretch server to install `bird`.

After deinstalling `quagga`, I have found out that I am unable to install any other package.

Whenever I try to install any new package, I got back the error:

```
unknown user 'quagga' in statoverride file
```

What to do?

Comment: That’s odd, uninstalling `quagga` shouldn’t have removed the corresponding system user... I know you found a workaround, but could you please file a bug too? The main issue is that the `statoverride` setup in the `postinst` doesn’t have a corresponding removal in the `postrm`.

Comment: @StephenKitt I may file a bug later on. I am done with `quagga` in Debian after them dropping SysV support abruptly. I will have to test with their new packages still have this bug. I edited the question to add the version.

Comment: Ah, right, you uninstalled an old version... That old version did indeed remove the system user, the current version doesn’t, which would avoid the issue. (That’s actually a decent tip in general: paradoxically, before uninstalling an old package, make sure it’s up-to-date, even if that involves losing the initscripts.)

Comment: I confirmed it, 1.1.1 is not affected; it does not affect Jessie too. Interesting.

Comment: @StephenKitt Doing today the final migration to `bird`: it did not happen with 2 more servers, but it happened again with a 4th server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the line

```
quagga quaggavty 775 /etc/quagga
```

in the file `/var/lib/dpkg/statoverride`.

After deleting that line, I was able to install `bird`.

Apparently, the *oficial* way to do it is (this also happened later on another server, and this time I used this form):

```
sudo dpkg-statoverride --remove /etc/quagga
```

And to list all overrides:

```
dpkg-statoverride --list
```

From [man dpkg-statoverride](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/dpkg-statoverride.8.html)

> ```
>    --remove path
>           Remove an override for path, the status of path is left
>           unchanged by this command.
>
>    --list [glob-pattern]
>           List all overrides. If a glob pattern is specified restrict
>           the output to overrides which match the glob. If there are no
>           overrides or none match the glob dpkg-statoverride will exit
>           with an exitcode of 1.
> ```